# execute bash script from raspberry pi using a button in android java

Tags: java, android, linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have written a script to start my raspberry pi camera and now wish to be able to execute this script remotely from my android phone I have the pi set up as a access point and am able to connect and view whats on the camera from my pi on phone. The code I have been trying with is this and was wondering if anyone hand any clues or tips?

```
networkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                String IPAddress = "10.0.0.1";
                String script= "home/pi/start.sh";
                //String script= "~/home/pi/start.sh";
                String[] cmd = {script, IPAddress};
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                rt.exec(cmd);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "This script has started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: start some php server on PI, make dynamic page/web service which calls this script on PI, then call this page from android ... or find telnet/ssh library for android connect to your PI with it and call the script with telnet/ssh session ...

Comment: don't you want `"/home/pi/..."`? (note the leading `/` char). Good luck.